# C# Access Data in VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm creating a VSTO addin.  I want to create a dictionary once as outlook starts that I can then access from methods within the OutlookRibbon class.  What is the best practice or proper method to create such a dictionary?  I currently have the method where the dictionary is created in the method that uses it which is very inefficient as it's called every time.  Here is the code:

```
public partial class OutlookRibbon
{
    private void OutlookRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        genMyDict();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Archive();
    }
    void genMyDict()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> myDict= new Dictionary<string, string>();
        myDict.Add("@x.com", "x");
        // many lines of this

    }

    void Archive()
    {
        if (myDict.ContainsKey("@x.com")) { // run code }
    }
```

Obviously this throws an error myDict does not exist in the current context in Archive()

How should I structure this so that the dictionary is only created one time but can still be accessed from my other methods within OutlookRibbon class?   I can't seem to make it work.  Is there a better way to create a dict for use like this in a VSTO outlook addin?

Comment: Shameless plug-> Check out my article [C# Dictionary<T> Tricks](http://omegacoder.com/?p=188) for some cool ways to manipulate dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> myDict does not exist in the current context

Change the scope of the dictionary by making it a property of the `OutlookRibbon` class. That will expand its scope away from the method `genMyDict`'s *localized stack*.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary { get; set; }

void genMyDict()
{
    MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    MyDictionary.Add("@x.com", "x");
    ...
}

void Archive()
{
    if (MyDictionary.ContainsKey("@x.com")) { // run code }
}
```

That will allow everything to access it. For that change of the scope allows access from just one method to the whole class.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the constructor as I think It's  generated and I don't want to override it accidentally.

Comment: @shenk sorry I mistook the private method `genMyDict` as the constructor. So instead of assigning the dictionary in the constructor as I said, forget that, keep the allocation in `genMyDict` but assign it to the property you created for it on the class `OutlookRibbon`.

Comment: can you give me a small example?

Comment: @Shenk where does it happen?

Comment: On the ContainsKey method, object reference not set to an instance of the object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76590/discussion-between-omegaman-and-shenk).